# Как изменить css стили товаров в Woocommerce и div'ы, в которые они оборачиваются?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

На этой картинке показано, как выводятся товары с помощью шорткода

```
[recent_products per_page="4" columns="4"]:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем, это карусель, т.е. она может мотаться курсором влево и вправо.

При помощи каких хуков можно это реализовать и как поставить свои стили для товаров?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком глобально ставите вопрос. В рамках ответа изложить полный курс кастомизации woocommerce не получится. Поэтому кратко, блоками.

Стили правятся как обычно, в `style.css` [дочерней темы](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html).

Далее вам надо переформатировать отображение товара. [Здесь](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/) приведена хорошая карта хуков, которые можно использовать для настройки этого отображения. Возможно, придётся изменить приоритет некоторых хуков, чтобы переставить местами блоки информации.

Ну, и последнее, сделать карусель. Плагинов для вывода карусели товаров не знаю, делал сам руками - немного css и js. Это не очень сложно. Вывод товаров из шорткода надо обернуть в `div` с `oveflow:hidden`. Ширину блока `.woocommerce`, который выводится шорткодом, пересчитать в js, в зависимости от количества товаров в карусели. Отменить у `li` товаров свойство `cler:both`, чтобы не было вывода в несколько рядов. И навесить стрелки слева и справа с `position:absolute`. При клике на стрелки высчитывать `margin: left` блока `.woocommerce` и изменять её.

Пример такого решения есть [тут](https://houselit.ru/). Весь css и js карусели доступен из браузера, можете просто скопировать.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю в браузере нажать F12 и посмотреть к чему какие стиле принадлежат. Потом просто изменить их и добавить новые если требуется.